# NuGet For Unity download packages and have error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nuget

I download packages ipfs.http and ipfs.engine.

And get error:

> C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.6f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\UI\Core\ToggleGroup.cs(122,30): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' and 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)'

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you check your imports? Are you importing both packages at the same time?

Comment: Are you talking about Ipfs.Engine and ipfs.http.client? If Yes, then Yes